# How to publish multiple commands (all or none) from a MassTransit Consume(IConsumeContext<T>) method

Tags: c#, transactions, rabbitmq, masstransit

I've implemented a competing consumer pattern via MassTransit (with RabbitMQ) and as a result of processing a single Command, need to Publish three other Commands.  I would like to do this in an "all or nothing" (transactional style) publish, where "all" would ensure that the three messages made it to RabbitMQ successfully, or none, where none of my 3 events would make it to RabbitMQ, even if it was publishing of the third one that failed.

Until now, I've been simply calling message.Respond(new MyNewCommandHere(){...}), but I don't see a bulk interface anywhere there or on the IServiceBus instance.

So...  Is it possible to do a bulk publish somehow, or some other recommended way to get this transactional publishing behavior?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "bulk publish" option. You can publish a type that implements 3 interfaces and they will be published serially.

MSMQ has transactional queues. You could open a transaction, send to two queues and roll back only if needed. I wouldn't recommend MSMQ though, RabbitMQ is a much more robust platform.

Is this an error you have encountered or are you trying to solve for a problem not yet encountered? MassTransit does have some retry attempts around connections. And if you publish during a consumer, it's hard to see the connection going down unless you have really long running consumers.

Comment: The 3 interface example is interesting - have an example of that you could point me to?  I'll be sticking with RabbitMQ, was curious if there was some buried bulk publish that maybe MassTransit was using behind the scenes, but I guess not.  As you guessed, this isn't something I've encountered, as it's very unlikely (and I just started queuing up multiple messages from a single consumer yesterday).  I was just trying to understand my options, and avoid unpredictable states if the trade-offs were fair. I'll just queue all 3 at the end with no delay.

Comment: If you have a message that implements 3 interfaces and each consumer just consumes one of those interfaces then you'd be set. MT publishes to all base types of a message if there are consumers for it.

Comment: Did you get a good enough example for this? Supporting multiple interfaces in a single publish is the best way to ensure that a single publish atomically publishes all three events in one go. Realize, this is a publish, so you may want to initiate your commands in response to these events. Be sure to include correlationIds so that you can keep track of the source of the event and related commands.